# Shiny selectInput produces a list of numbers

Tags: r, shiny

am wondering why this issue is happening and if there is a fix for it.  I create the following sql query below:

```
 CompanyNames<-sqlQuery(connection, 
                  paste("SELECT Companynm",
                        " FROM RiskMgm_Company",
                        " WHERE CompanyID = ParentID",
                        " ORDER BY Companynm"))
```

CompanyNames comes in the form of a database.  Now no matter how I try or which way I convert it the selectInput below provides me with a list from 1 to 118 rather than the company names...  Any idea why and how to fix?

```
output$CompNameSelector <- renderUI({
selectInput("compName","Company Name:",c(CompanyNames$Companynm))
})
```

Thanks!

The SQL query returns a data.frame object with 1 variable and 118 observations.  All these observations are simply text.  Performing
   `class(CompanyNames$Companynm)`
provides a factor type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your example isn't [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I'm going to guess that `class(CompanyNames$Companynm)` is a "factor" rather than a "character". When you use `c()` on a factor, it strips all the information used for the levels and converts it to a simple numeric column. For example

```
x<-data.frame(a=c("apple","banana","pear"))
x$a 
# [1] apple  banana pear  
# Levels: apple banana pear
c(x$a)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

so don't use `c()` unnecessarily. That should just be used for concatenating vectors. To be safe, convert the factor to a character value with

```
output$CompNameSelector <- renderUI({
    selectInput("compName","Company Name:",
        as.character(CompanyNames$Companynm))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately that doesn't work either.  Yes when i use class(CompanyNames$Companynm) I get "factor".  However using just CompanyNames$Companynm still just gives me a list of numbers :(

Comment: That worked a charm thank you!  Sorry I couldn't provide much more than I gave